# How to get the active instance template name in a managed instance group

Tags: templates, instance, gcloud

I am trying to get the instance template name of an instance group.  In the GCP console, the instance template is included in the display (see sample screenshot).  However, i cannot find a gcloud command that will give this info, for example:

gcloud compute instance-groups describe xxxx-instance-group --region=us-central1 --project=project_xxx

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to `gcloud` currently but your either using the wrong command or the default output does not include the template.

IIRC templates only apply to managed IGs. There's a `gcloud` subcommand [`gcloud compute instance-groups managed describe`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/describe) that should include the value. If the default command does but, try appending e.g. `--format=yaml`.

A good way to corroborate this is using [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer). For the Compute Engine service there's a  Managed Instance Group resource that does include template. See the response body for [`regionInstanceGroupManagers.get`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/regionInstanceGroupManagers/get)

Comment: omg, i am an idiot.  i am able to get the instance template now, the difference was, like you said, missing "managed" in that command. lol.  thanks!